# Spring MVC and show Validation in process

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, spring-mvc

I am using the following UserValidator Code in SpringMVC. The code works fine. But, I am not sure how will I implement the validating with the database.

Since, it is with database connectivity, it should be done in background and show the user a progress bar.

So, how should I implement this functionality, considering a JSP as a View.

```
    package core;

    import org.springframework.validation.Errors;
    import org.springframework.validation.ValidationUtils;
    import org.springframework.validation.Validator;

    public class UserValidator implements Validator {

        @Override
        public boolean supports(Class arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return User.class.isAssignableFrom(arg0);
        }

        @Override
        public void validate(Object arg0, Errors errors) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            ValidationUtils.rejectIfEmpty(errors, "UserName", "message.userName");
            ValidationUtils.rejectIfEmpty(errors, "password", "message.password");
            ValidationUtils.rejectIfEmpty(errors, "repassword", "message.reenterpassword");

            User user=(User)arg0;
            if(!errors.hasErrors() && !(user.getPassword().equals(user.getRepassword()))){
                errors.rejectValue("repassword", "message.passwordDifferent");
            }else{
                //Connect to database, validate for duplicate username and insert into DataBase if required
}
        }

    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can annotate your validator with `@Component` then autowire your DAO to do the database call. I did the same thing with my project.

Here's an example:-

```
@Component
public class UserValidator implements Validator {

    @Autowired
    private MyDAO myDAO;

    ...

}
```

Keep in mind, your validation class **should only perform validation**. It's probably not a good idea to modify the data in DB here. In fact, your controller should instruct your service class to do that if there's no validation error. So, your controller will look something like this:-

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping(value = "/login")
public class LoginController {

    @Autowired
    private UserService userService;

    @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public ResponseEntity login(@Valid @ModelAttribute LoginForm loginForm, BindingResult result, Model model) {

        if (result.hasErrors()) {
            return new ResponseEntity(HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST);
        }

        // save to DB here
        userService.saveUsernameIfNotDuplicate(...);

        return new ResponseEntity(HttpStatus.OK);
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you please add a small example, that would really help me

Comment: But, where to do I add the code to show "Validation in process".  saveUsernameIfNotDuplicate should be performed in background.

Comment: Are you doing AJAX call to perform the validation? If so, your JS can display that "Validation in process" text after you make the AJAX call to this controller. I modified the above controller example to return `ResponseEntity` object in this case.

Comment: No, I am not using AJAX. But, I will use it now.I am using a SimpleFormContorller and no annotation. So, In my case I will have to replace the method name of "login" with the following protected ModelAndView onSubmit(Object obj) throws Exception